# email magento testimonial link not redirect admin custom module edit page

Tags: adminhtml, url, email-templates, link, magento-1.9.2.1

I Sent an email to Admin and the email contains some text and testimonial links and link URL is `http://example.com/index.php/admin_test/adminhtml_testimonial/edit/id/1/key/91c0259ce0f94dda2cf0467d4f0bba97/` and Admin already logged in and when Admin clicks on the above link from gmail account it redirects `dashboard` page rather than the testimonial edit form page. I am using `Magento 1.9.2` with all security patches. 
I used this code for link url `Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('admin_test/adminhtml_testimonial/edit', array('id'=> $testimonialId)`

Why it redirect dashboard page ?

Comment: This depends on the router configuration in your module. Please update your question with that info

Comment: But if Admin logged in and I disable secret key from system > configuration > Admin and then send email and now link url is   http://example.com/index.php/admin_test/adminhtml_testimonial/edit/id/1/  and when I click this link from email it will work and redirect to edit form page.issue about in secret key ?

Comment: Ah, yes, for those external links you do need to turn off the secret key, you might not want to do that.

Comment: it is stated that they have added secret key to URL for CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) Attack Prevention.Any Magento Email template available where link to redirect to admin edit form page ?

Comment: Since they key is based on a certain session I don't think it's possible to actually make a direct link to be honest. Not without sacrificing security